# What standard is this very coarse screw?

Tags: screws

I was repairing Sony headphones when I saw some screws were missing. As all screws were the same, I took off a non missing screw to see what size and thread it was.

I measured the outer diameter and it was 2mm. I measured the pitch and it was around 0.6mm. What standard is that? M2 would have 3 times smaller of a pitch. What standard is typically used in electronic devices? Where can I find this type of screw?

Comment: Is it screwed into plastic? These have coarse threads and aren't nearly as standardized as screws for metal.

Answer (score 4):

The type of screw that you describe is a special design with a large pitch on the the threads to create its own threads in the mating plastic part. You can find these at McMaster-Carr  or other specialty fastener supplier.

[image]

([Link to supplier page for 6mm length](https://www.mcmaster.com/96817a844)).

([Link to another supplier page for 6mm](https://us.screwerk.com/en/shop/detail/stp/STP39A0200060E.html)).

Comment: Known in the UK as "self-tapping screws".

Comment: Most the self tapping screws, as opposed to the thread forming type above, that I have used have either a notched cutting edge at the tip or are tapered at the end with thread all the way to the tip. Thread pitch is also much closer (less steep).

Comment: Wood screws are like this; they are not standard-thread "machine" screws. It shouldn't matter too much if your replacement is exactly the same thread; repeated use of the same hole will gradually degrade holding power even with the same thread, in soft materials.